# Microsoft Teams : Placing Created Team in hidden list once created

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have an app that is used to create various teams in the microsoft teams app via the use of the Microsoft Graph API. This app creates a group with an associated team and then adds members to that team depending on criteria.

However once the team is created, the members of the team see the newly created team in the "Your Teams" list, this list can get long so to make it easier I automatically place the team in the "Hidden Teams" list.

In order to do this I would archive and then unarchive a team, this would automatically place the team in the "Hidden Teams" list for all members.

Recently I have run into an issue where archiving the team works, but when trying to unarchive the team, I would get a "object not set to an instance of an object" error returned from the method.

This behaviour is new and causes my application to break, whereas for the last couple of months the app behaved fine, i was wondering if there is another way to automatically add the created team to the hidden teams list.

Comment: Could you please re-check on the documentation for Graph API.
Also could you please share the repro steps or docs which you are following.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no Teams / Graph API to set the Visible/Hidden state of a Team in a User's view.

I expect that in your approach users will still get notified of them being added to a team , only then to find that the teams has been archived and or hidden.

I suggest that it might be simpler and more understandable for end-users to separate

- the automated creation of the Teams
  this will allow you to do any setup / configuration
- Adding users to the Teams

  - which makes them visible ,
  - and show notifications to all users added